# Does measurability/continuity of a mapping follow that of its sections?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose  $\{ (G_i, \mathcal{G}_i), i=1,2 \}$ are measurable spaces. Their product measurable space is $(\prod_{i=1}^2 G_i, \prod_{i=1}^2 \mathcal{G}_i)$.

$(F, \mathcal{F})$ is another measurable space.

$g:\prod_{i=1}^2 G_i \rightarrow F $ is a mapping. Define sections of $g$ on each component space $G_i$ as follows

$\forall x_1 \in G_1$ define $g_{x_1}:
    G_2 \rightarrow F$ as $g_{x_1}(x_2) := g(x_1,x_2)$;

$\forall x_2 \in G_2$ define $g_{x_2}:
    G_1 \rightarrow F$ as $g_{x_2}(x_1) := g(x_1,x_2)$.

1. Similar to Theorem 18.1 of Probability and Measure by Billingsley, it can be
   shown that if $g$ is measurable, then its sections are all
   measurable. I was wondering if the converse is also true, i.e. if
   its sections are all measurable, is $g$ also measurable?
2. If it is true, will it still be true for arbitrarily many $\{ (G_i,
       \mathcal{G}_i), i=I \}$?
3. I am also wondering about the same questions when replacing
   measurable spaces with topological spaces, and measurability of a
   mapping by continuity of a mapping? (I will move this topological
   case to another post if the answers are not essentially based on the same idea.)

Thanks and regards!

Comment: In 1920 Sierpiński [constructed an example](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm1/fm1113.pdf) of a non-Lebesgue measurable subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ intersecting each line in at most two points. This implies of course that $S$ intersects each horizontal and vertical line in at most two points, so that the sections of the characteristic function $[S]: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are all measurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take for example $G_1 = G_2 = [0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and let $A$ be a non-Borel subset of the diagonal.  (For example, let $E$ be a non-Borel subset of $[0,1]$ and let $A = \{ (x,x) : x \in E \}$.)  Then the indicator function $1_A$ is not measurable, but you can check that all of its sections are.

Comment: I was wondering why when $E$ is non-Borel, the intersection of $E$ and the diagonal is also non-Borel?

Comment: @Tim: Read again; $A$ is not the intersection of $E$ with the diagonal.  $E$ is a subset of $[0,1]$, not $[0,1]^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry,for misunderstanding. Why is $A$ non-Borel measurable?

Comment: @Tim: Consider the map $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ defined by $f(x) = (x,x)$.  $f$ is continuous hence Borel measurable.  But  $E = f^{-1}(A)$, so if $A$ were Borel $E$ would also be Borel.

Answer (score 7):

For (3) consider the function $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2},&\text{if }\langle x,y\rangle\ne\langle 0,0\rangle\\\\
0,&\text{if }x=y=0\;;
\end{cases}$$ $f$ is easily seen to be discontinuous at the origin, but all of its sections are continuous.

**Added:** For background and references on separate versus joint continuity see Z. Piotrowski, *Separate versus joint continuity - an update*, Proc. 29th Spring Conference Union Bulg. Math. Lovetch (2000), 93-106, available [here](http://people.ysu.edu/%7Ezpiotrowski/newpub.htm) as Nr. 51.

T.O. Banakh, O.V. Maslyuchenko, & V.V. Mykhaylyuk show in *Discontinuous separately continuous functions and near coherence of $P$-filters* that for every non-discrete Tikhonov space $X$ there are a Tikhonov space $Y$ with a unique non-isolated point and a bounded separately continuous $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R}$ that is not jointly continuous and use this result to show

> **Theorem:** For any non-discrete Tikhonov space $X$ there are a $\sigma$-bounded Abelian topological group $G$ and separately continuous $h:X\times G\to \mathbb{R}$ that is not jointly continuous.

The paper is available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-32/issue-2/Discontinuous-Separately-Continuous-Functions-and-Near-Coherence-of-P-Filters/rae/1199377476.full).

For (1), Maxim R. Burke, *Borel measurability of separately continuous functions*, Topology and its Applications 129 (2003), 29–65, mentions that Walter Rudin, in *Lebesgue’s first theorem* (in L. Nachbin (Ed.), *Mathematical Analysis and Applications*, Part B, in *Advances in Mathematics Supplementary Studies*, Vol. 7B, Academic Press, New York, 1981, pp. 741–747), gives a ‘very simple example of a non-Borel separately continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$’, but I’ve not seen it. In *Borel measurability of separately continuous functions, II*, Topology and its Applications 134 (2003), 159–188, he notes that D.K. Burke & R. Pol, *On Borel sets in function spaces with the weak topology*, J. London Math. Soc.(2) 68 (2003), 725–738, have shown that if $X$ is an infinite compact $F$-space without isolated points or a Baire $P$-space without isolated points, then the evaluation map $e:X\times C_p(X)\to\mathbb{R}:\langle x,f\rangle\mapsto f(x)$ is not Borel measurable, though it is separately continuous. (A space $X$ is an $F$-space if every cozero set in $X$ is $C^*$-embedded in $X$. there are many compact $F$-spaces, since $\beta X\setminus X$ is an $F$-space whenever $X$ is a $\sigma$-compact, locally compact space. A $P$-space is a topological space in which every $G_\delta$-set is open.)

Comment: +1 Thanks! Especially the references are great, and you even mentioned the mixed case of jointly measurability and separate continuity that I didn't think of. If I could, I wish I could have accepted all three replies. My bad that I asked questions in two different areas.

Comment: @PatrickT: Thanks; I’ve updated the link to the Banakh et al. paper.

Answer (score 3):

For continuity, the answer is no (at least if I'm interpreting your definition of continuity for "sections" correctly).  Here is the standard counterexample.  Define a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$.  Clearly $f$ is continuous away from $(0,0)$, but it is an easy exercise (that I usually give when teaching calculus) that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.  However, the functions $f(0,y)=0$ and $f(x,0)=0$ are definitely continuous.